# Call this number from the United Kingdom?

Tags: phone-networks

Not sure if this is the right board, but it's the closest one I can find. I'm trying to find a way to call this number `800.893.893` from the UK.

Google says simply dial `00` first as this is the exit code, however dialing `00 800 893 890` doesn't work, the call immediately ends.

Also tried adding 39 which is the country code, so `00 39 800 893 890` however this is an invalid number.

Number is in Italy.

Comment: Which country is the number from? Have you added the country code?

Comment: Damn sorry, forgot add that! Updated post, it's in Italy.

Comment: Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Italy), it seems that Italian `80...` numbers are toll-free, like British `0800` numbers. The owner of a toll-free number can choose to have it only available domestically (there'll be higher costs for accepting international calls). I don't know for certain if that applies in Italy, but it seems likely. It may be that this particular number just isn't available if you're calling from a non-Italian number. In that case, your best option will be to find other means of contact (i.e. a standard phone number, email, etc)

Comment: @ChrisH I have tried all their numbers and none of them seem to work. I'm trying to contact https://www.poste.it/cerca as they have had my parcel in customs for nearly 3 months.

Comment: I doubt there's much else we can do to help you here, but [this](https://twitter.com/PosteSpedizioni/with_replies) seems to be the Poste Italiane customer service twitter account. It appears to be responding relatively quickly (although most responses are just requesting further details be sent in a private message, so I don't know how long it takes for any actual resolution as that isn't public). If you don't already use twitter, it might be worth setting up an account to contact them there.. Best of luck!

Comment: A quirk of dialling [Italian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Italy) from outside Italy is that you need to dial the initial 0 in an ordinary number, which is usually dropped when dialling internationally. So a regular number will start 00 39 0... I don't know if this applies to freephone numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment OP has indicated they they are trying to contact the Italian Post Office - they list an additional phone number: +390659581 in the footer of some of their webpages (for example: https://www.posteitaliane.it/en/mail-parcel-and-distribution.html). Which at least for from my UK mobile also works to reach them.

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope someone there can speak English!